# how can I check and kill another instance of my application?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, kill-process

I face to a problem that my customer is already running the application appA. Then they go to desktop (not kill the appA), and upgrade the application with the version up by run appA.ps1 with PowerShell. After that, click on appA after installed -> `get an exception`. I guess the root cause is that have another instance is running.

**My question is how can I check my application is already running? Can I kill it?**

Additional, my application is windows 8 store, c#.

Comment: Are you sure the exception is caused by the side loaded upgrade? And what exception is happening?

Answer (score 7):

If you wand to keep your current instance running and kill all other instances of your application, you can do this:

```
 using namespace System.Diagnostics;

 ...

 // get current process
 Process current = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
 // get all the processes with currnent process name
 Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(current.ProcessName);
 
 foreach (Process process in processes)
 {
     //Ignore the current process  
     if (process.Id != current.Id)
     {
        process.Kill();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Social MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/14e2be68-ef86-4480-a3fd-6ddf7ec7d1f1/how-to-start-a-external-program-from-metro-app?forum=winappswithcsharp):

> All the Metro-style applications work in the highly sandboxed environment and there is no way to directly start an external application.

You cannot access windows app processes. Unfortunately, you aren't able to check for running windows apps.

I didn't find another way so far.

---

**No Metro-style application**

At first, you need the processes:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("your application name")
```

To check whether your program is already running:

```
var isRunning = processes.Length > 1;
```

Then you loop through them and close the processes:

```
foreach (var process in processes)
{
    process.CloseMainWindow();

    // OR more aggressive:
    process.Kill();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me which preferences for Process in Windows 8 store? And how to add this preference on Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Sorry, at the moment I'm on a Win 7 system. Are you sure you cannot catch win8 store processes with this way?

Comment: Yes, Win8 store cannot catch the processes with this way.

Comment: @thanhzusu I updated my answer. Unfortunately, it is not possible.